# How I can call a java class before starting a process?

Tags: java, camunda

I try create camunda form with select tag:

```
        <select
                required
                id="Assignment"
                cam-variable-name="Assignment"
                cam-choices="assignments"
                cam-variable-type="String">
        </select>
```

I need to fill it with values from the database when opening a form (before starting the process).  But camunda not have form starter listener.

What I can use way for this?

Comment: You can do it in another process. To do this you simply start a program with no UI/form, then get the data you need from the database, then call the form class to create/display the form using that information.

Comment: @sorifiend In camunda I don't start a program with no UI/form/ And I don't know which class belongs to the form class

Comment: Is this a Java or a Javascript question? I don't know anything about camunda, but in either language there is always an option to preload the data from one source before using it in another place. If you must load the form, then don't display any fields until the data is loaded, or use an empty form until you can load the data, then there should be no issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on such a design then the answer is either a service task, an execution listener or a task listener. Please see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/delegation-code/

However, if you do not require the data as process data for other purposes then you could simply call the service which provides the data directly from the UI, based on a primary key which you carry as process data.